# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 33 path $.data

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I got a problem here .
I am using Kotlin ,retrofit and Gson .
I need to create a user ,and insert it into the userList .
However ,I got an error here,which is :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 33 path $.data
```

Could you please take a look ,what is going on with my code please ,thank you so much in advance !

**RetrofitInstance.kt**

```
    class RetrofitInstance {
        companion object{
            const val baseUrl = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/"
            fun getRetrofitInstance():Retrofit{
                val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .writeTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()
                return Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            }
        }
    }

**RetrofitService.kt** 


interface RetrofitService {
    //1.get all users
    //https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users
    @GET("users")
    @Headers("Accept:application/json","Content-Type:application/json")
     fun getUsersList() : Call<UserList>

     //2.search user by name
     //https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users?name=c2
     @GET("users")
     @Headers("Accept:application/json","Content-Type:application/json")
     fun searchUsers(@Query("name")username:String):Call<UserList>

     //3.create a user
     @POST("users")
     @Headers("Accept:application/json", "Content-Type:application/json",
         "Authorization: Bearer c0e900498b9d4b6bec02d4cff795de8187cf751f9a6074c9645b0730f9dfc3dd")
     fun createUser(@Body params:User) : Call<UserResponse>


}
```

**UserAdapter.kt** (This is for the show users list ,in case there is somthing wrong ,I posted it also)

```
class UserAdapter(private var fragment: Fragment):RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
  var usersList:List<User> = listOf()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
       val binding:UserItemBinding = UserItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(fragment.context),parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
      holder.bind(usersList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return usersList.size
    }



    class ViewHolder(view:UserItemBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view.root) {
        val item_id = view.txtId
        val item_name = view.txtName
        val item_email = view.txtEmail
        val item_gender = view.txtGender
        val item_more = view.imgMore

        fun bind(data:User){
            item_name.text = data.name
            item_email.text = data.email
            item_gender.text = data.gender
        }

    }
}
```

**CreateUserActivity**
This Activity is for create new user ,and I got suck here ..After I clicked the upload button ,it appears the error ..

```
class AddAndUpdateActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   private lateinit var binding:ActivityAddAndUpdateBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel : CreateUserViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityAddAndUpdateBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        initViewModel()
        createUserObservable()


     
        binding.btnUploadUpdate.setOnClickListener {
          createUser()
        }
    }



    private fun initViewModel() {
       viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CreateUserViewModel::class.java)

    }

    private fun createUserObservable() {
       viewModel.getCreateNewUserObservable().observe(this, {
           if(it==null){
               Toast.makeText(this,"Fail to create user",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           }else{
               Toast.makeText(this,"Success!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               finish()
           }
       })
    }

    private fun createUser() {
        val username = binding.edtUserName.text.toString()
        val email = binding.edtEmail.text.toString()
        val gender = binding.edtGender.text.toString()
      val user = User("",username,email,gender)
        Log.e("haha","create user:"+user.id+" ,"+user.name+" ,"+user.email+" ,"+user.gender)
        viewModel.createUser(user)

    }



}
```

**CreateUserViewModel.kt**

```
class CreateUserViewModel:ViewModel() {
    
    var createUserLiveData:MutableLiveData<UserResponse?> = MutableLiveData()
    fun getCreateNewUserObservable():MutableLiveData<UserResponse?> {
        return createUserLiveData
    }
  
    fun createUser(user: User){
        val retrofitInstance = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitService::class.java)
        val call = retrofitInstance.createUser(user)
        call.enqueue(object: Callback<UserResponse?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserResponse?>, response: Response<UserResponse?>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    createUserLiveData.postValue(response.body())
                }else{
                    createUserLiveData.postValue(null)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse?>, t: Throwable) {
                createUserLiveData.postValue(null)
                Log.e("haha","error reason："+t.message.toString())
            }

        })
    }
}
```

**UserList.kt**
Here are the User entity:

```
data class UserList(val data: List<User> )

@Entity
@Parcelize
data class User(
    val id: String?,
    val name: String?,
    val email: String?,
    val gender: String?,

) : Parcelable

data class UserResponse(val code:Int?,val meta:String?,val data:User?)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it seems that the JSON contains an array of Users, whereas the UserResponse expects a single object. Hence, the parsing fails.

The UserResponse should be updated, so *data* will be of type *List*.

If this was the issue, I assume you may have solved it already.

Comment: Hi Robert,yes ,it is what you assume ,thank you so much !